# Do the && and || operators convert their operands to booleans?

Tags: javascript

Flanagan's O'Reilly JavaScript book states:

> Unlike the && and || operators, the ! operator converts its operand to
>   a boolean value [...] before inverting the converted value.

If those logical operators don't convert the operands to booleans, how can the expression be evaluated?

Comment: See also [JavaScript type conversion: (true && 1) vs (true | | 1)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8559920/712765)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 11.11: Binary Logical Operators:

The production [of evaluating `&&`] ... is evaluated as follows:

1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
3. If `ToBoolean(lval)` is false, return lval.
4. Let rref be the result of evaluating BitwiseORExpression.
5. Return GetValue(rref).

The production [of evaluating `||`] ... is evaluated as follows:

1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalORExpression.
2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
3. If `ToBoolean(lval)` is true, return lval.
4. Let rref be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
5. Return GetValue(rref).

So *internally* the value is "converted to a boolean". However, since this is never exposed -- and the entire semantic explanation is an abstraction which can be/is "optimized out" -- the behavior of `&&` and `||` can be simply explained through using truthy-and-falsy values (for which `ToBoolean` covers: a truthy-value is one for which `ToBoolean` returns true, all other values are falsy).

The logical table for `&&` is:

```
a       b      result
truthy  any    b
falsy   any    a
```

The logic table for `||` is:

```
a       b      result
truthy  any    a
falsy   any    b
```

Note that either the evaluation of `a` or `b` is returned.

Happy coding.

---

For completeness, from section 9.2:

The abstract operation `ToBoolean` converts its argument to a value of type boolean as ...

- Undefined - false
- Null - false
- boolean (not Boolean object!) - The result equals the input argument (no conversion).
- number (not Number object!) - The result is false if the argument is +0, -0, or NaN; otherwise the result is  true.
- string (not String object!) - The result is  false  if the argument is the empty String  (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.
- Object - true

Comment: Thanks!
Could there be a distinction between saying that a JavaScript expression is falsey and that it is false?

Comment: @ppecher: "falsey" means a value that "acts like" `false` when a boolean value is expected. In other words anything that `ToBoolean` would convert to `false`. So, `""`, `0`, `null`, etc. are all "falsey". "false" means the actual boolean value, `false`.

Comment: @ppecher: When you say "false", most people will think that it *is* a boolean (with a value of false). When you say "falsy", most people will understand that it is a value that, if converted to a boolean, would be false, but is not necessarily a boolean itself.

Answer (score 11):

They *do* convert the values to boolean, but *only* to determine how to proceed in evaluating the expression. The *result* of the expression is not necessarily boolean (in fact, if neither of your operands are boolean, it will **not** give you a boolean):

```
var x = false || 'Hello' // gives you 'Hello'
var y = 0 && 1           // gives you 0, because 0 is "falsy" and short circuits
var z = 1 || 2           // gives you 1, because 1 is "truthy" and short circuits
```

Comment: It does indeed invoke `ToBoolean` (under section 11.11 of the ECMAScript ed. 5) ... no votes left, but this is correct.

Comment: Exactly. If you put `true && 0` into a JS console, the output will be `0`, but if you put `if(true && 0) { true; } else { false; }`, the output will be `false`.

Comment: Ha ha yes, that's true.  I'm teaching it (informally) to a bunch of 13 year olds at present, and I have to wonder what they'll think when they see other boring languages someday :-)

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the return value

Answer (score 1):

The operands are interpreted as booleans for evaluating the expression, but the return value of && or || is always one of the operands.

For example:

```
true && 0 === 0, not false
1 || false === 1, not true
```

Comment: Since we have differing answers, does anyone have documentation to point us to?

Answer (score -1):

Because JavaScript has an idea of [truthiness](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html) that covers more than booleans.