# JavaScript type conversion: (true && 1) vs (true | | 1)

Tags: javascript, numbers, boolean, type-conversion

JavaScript is non-strictly typed language as Java,for example.

As we know, it converts value of result dependently upon context:

`"2" + "3"` results `"23"`

`"2" * "3"` results `6`

This is quite clear and OK for understanding.

I just tried following expressions and got confused:

`true && 1` results `1` 
`true || 1` results `true`

Why the first gives Number and the second gives boolean?

Considering JavaScript conversion rules,I expect to get `boolean` values in both cases,due to `boolean` context of expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [Douglas Crockford's site](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html), it says:

> The && operator is commonly called logical and. It can also be called
>   guard. If the first operand is false, null, undefined, "" (the empty
>   string), or the number 0 then it returns the first operand. Otherwise,
>   it returns the second operand. This provides a convenient way to write
>   a null-check:

```
var value = p && p.name; /* The name value will only be retrieved from
p if p has a value, avoiding an error. */
```

> The || operator is commonly
>   called logical or. It can also be called default. If the first operand
>   is false, null, undefined, "" (the empty string), or the number 0,
>   then it returns the second operand. Otherwise, it returns the first
>   operand. This provides a convenient way to specify default values:

```
value = v || 10; /* Use the value of v, but if v doesn't have a value,
use 10 instead. */
```

Comment: thank you for explanation - it's interesting point about guard and default

Comment: You're welcome. All in all, I would recommend to read Douglas' page on JavaScript instead of the specification. It's a lot easier to understand in my opinion. http://javascript.crockford.com/

Comment: Great explanation!  I wish I could give you +3.

Comment: @OldPro well thanks, but credit where credit is due it's all Douglas Crockford's.

Answer (score 9):

To [quote MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators);

> **&&;** Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

> **||**; Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns false.

So in the first example, `1` is being returned because `expr1` cannot be converted to false.

In the second example, `true` can be converted to true, so it's returned.

Comment: many thanks,actually you remind me,that Mozilla resource is very valuable as JavaScript documentation

Answer (score 9):

This has nothing to do with type conversion.

`||` returns the first truthy operand.  `1 || true` will give you `1`

`&&` returns the first falsy operand, or the second operand if both are truthy.

See page 58 of the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

`true && 1` => this will always return the last value of && if all conditions are true or false otherwise

`true || 1` => this will always return the first 'truthy' value

Resources:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can do other things too like:

```
var myVar = Math.random() > 0.5;

myVar && doFunc();
```

which is the same as

```
if(myVar) {
    doFunc();
}
```

The `||` basically means "If the first thing is false, go to second"

The `&&` basically means "If the first thing is true, go to the second"

This is why you see things like this at the top of functions:

```
function myFunction(options) {
    options = options || {};
}
```

Which means: If options is falsey, make it `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing casting (the * / + operators will do this) with logical evaluation (which &&, ||) do.