# Does the logic keyword || only get the value true or false?

Tags: javascript

The following code is from 'JavaScript by Example Second Edition' EXAMPLE 15.24
I don't understand the code var evt = e || window.event; //Browser differences
I think the var evt should be true or false, so evt.target should be null, right?

```
function colorText(e){
  var evt = e || window.event; //Browser differences
  var evtTarget= evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if(evtTarget.id=="first"){
div1.className="red";
}
else if(evtTarget.id == "second"){
div2.className="blue";
}
else{ div3.className="green";}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do the && and || operators convert their operands to booleans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601962/do-the-and-operators-convert-their-operands-to-booleans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <strike>keyword</strike> expression returns the value of the first <strike>expression</strike> operand if it's not <strike>null</strike> falsey, otherwise  the value of the second.

<strike>Javascript is weak typed, so you can always use || as a boolean, because everything which isn't false or null evaluates to true. But it's actually returning the value here, s</strike>. So `evt` becomes either `e` (the argument) or if `e` <strike>doesn't exist</strike> has a falsey value, it becomes `window.event`.

Answer (score 4):

All of the answers so far are technically true. The full story:

The || operator returns the value of the first operand if the result of casting it to a boolean value is truthy. Otherwise, it returns the value of the second operand.  [ES5 Spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.11)

Many different values are "falsy", including null and undefined. [Nailing down exactly what falsy is can be tricky](http://zero.milosz.ca/), but you can count on those, which is useful for catching variables and properties that may not be present in different browsers. If you want to check for an undefined variable yourself, though, it's usually best to use typeof instead.

Answer (score 2):

If `e` is not set, meaning you did not call the function with a parameter, then `evt` will be `window.event`. If `e` is set, then `evt` will be whatever `e` is.

There's a concept known as [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and that means if the condition is met without fully evaluating it, then it doesn't need to fully evaluate it. That is the case here. If `e` is set, you don't care what `window.event` is, because you already have something you can set `evt` to.

Comment: Question: How did you get that codeblock formatting to be inline with the rest of your sentence? Also, what is the syntax for codeblock formatting text to look like a command?

Comment: Wrap the text in a backtick `. Check [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

No, in JavaScript || does not cast to boolean, instead it short-circuits to which ever value (from left to right) first evaluates as truthy.

It preserves the expression's evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var evt = e || window.event;
```

This line sets the variable evt to e if e is not empty. Otherwise (if e is null, for example if e was not passed to this function), evt is set to window.event.