# Logical AND (&&) and OR (||) operators

Tags: javascript

Logical AND (`&&`) and OR (`||`) operators --- who knew they could trick us like this :)

Their definition, for JS (according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) explanation), is the following:

> expr1 **&&** expr2 => Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false;
>   otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, &&
>   returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns false.
>
> expr1 **||** expr2 => Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true;
>   otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, ||
>   returns true if either operand is true; if both are false, returns
>   false.

Testing it, indeed it works just as the definition, but here's the problem:

```
false || ""  //returns ""
"" || false  //returns false
```

So, obviously:

```
(false || "") ==  ("" || false) // true
```

But, sadly

```
(false || "") === ("" || false) // false
```

To the main two questions:

1. Is this a bug, or why is JavaScript forcing us to use `==` operator ***or***
   to pay attention to the order when using `&&` and `||` operators?
2. Why is javascript unable to convert expr1 to `true` in this expression
   `("" || false)`?. I mean, isn't it as simple as prepending `""` with the
   NOT (`!`) operator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do the && and || operators convert their operands to booleans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601962/do-the-and-operators-convert-their-operands-to-booleans)

Comment: "==" forces a type conversion. avoiding it always good

Comment: The answer is in the question. `expr1 || expr2 => Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2`. In the last case you have `"" === false` that's false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just how they work. It's not a bug:

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; **otherwise, returns expr2**

This means you can use "default values", like this:

```
function someFunc(passedParameter){
    var newValue = passedParameter || 1337
}
```

Or run functions when conditions are met:

```
var myBool = true;
myBool && someFunc(); // someFunc will only be evaluated if `myBool` is truthy
```

**[More info on truthy / falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)**

Comment: But it states `Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false`. You can't convert `"a"` to false? Try `!"a"` to see what it does.

Comment: `!"a"` is `true`, because `!` is a logical inversion. To convert something to a boolean, use double exclamation marks: `!!"a"`. Have a look at [what values are truthy or falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: This is interesting - never though of it that way. Thanks, you've clarified it all with `!!"a"` (because that's the actual conversion, I was thinking of inversion".

Comment: Eh, whoops, that's what I meant to say, @fast o.O