# Why in Javascript is it possible for a boolean operator to return neither false nor true?

Tags: javascript

```
var operand1 = null;
var operand2 = true;
var booleanOperatorReturnsABoolean = operand1 && operand2;
booleanOperatorReturnsABoolean == false || booleanOperatorReturnsABoolean == true
```

Result: **false**

Running this in a javascript console shows that the boolean operator (&&) sometimes may NOT result in a boolean

Comment: Have you looked this up? It has been brought up many times.

Comment: The logical AND and OR operators in JavaScript are not boolean operators. They are [short-circuit operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: [Do the && and || operators convert their operands to booleans?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601962/do-the-and-operators-convert-their-operands-to-booleans)

Comment: @AaditMShah: No, [they're _logical operators_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation) that _can_ short-circuit.

Comment: More like *illogical* operators `null && false == false && null || new Date("February 7, 2014").toDateString() == new Date("2014-02-07").toDateString() || 0.1+0.2==0.3`

Comment: @JonathanLeaders: That's your opinion, but the way they work makes perfect sense. In fact, it's pretty darn convenient compared to strictly returning `true`/`false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Because that's how they're designed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

`&&` returns the left side of the expression if it's `falsy`, otherwise, it returns the right side.
`||` returns the left side of the expression if it's `truthy`, otherwise, it returns the right side.

In cases where the left side is returned, the right side isn't even evaluated, allowing you to code shortcuts like:

```
var hasValue = "foobar" === someVariable;
hasValue && doSomething();
```

Here, `doSomething` will only be executed if `somevariable` equals `"foobar"`

Comment: I see this is false 
`null && false == false && null || new Date("February 7, 2014").toDateString() == new Date("2014-02-07").toDateString() || 0.1+0.2==0.3`

Comment: @JonathanLeaders: that whole line returns `true` for me...

Comment: That's exciting. I'm using mozilla's version of javascript through firefox & IE, I get `false` in the alert box here: http://jsfiddle.net/jleaders/8FAkv/3/